# Rotating CoordinatoLayout Performance Issues

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout

I am working on an application where I need to make a **circular layout**, which rotates as the user rotates the image. I have used a **CoordinatorLayout** for this purpose, but it leads to laggy animations, and even the NavigationDrawer has started lagging. Is there some way to take care of these issues?
Below is the TouchListener rotating the CoordinatorLayout.

```
private class MyOnTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener{
    private double startAngle;
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                startAngle = getAngle(event.getX(),event.getY());
                t.setText(""+startAngle);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                double currentAngle = getAngle(event.getX(),event.getY());
                double finalA = currentAngle-startAngle;
                RotateAnimation animation = new RotateAnimation((float)startAngle,(float)currentAngle,w/2,w/2);
                animation.setFillAfter(true);
                animation.setDuration(0);
                rl.setAnimation(animation);
                rl.startAnimation(animation);
                startAngle=currentAngle;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TF6JD.png) and
[How it rotates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTHrP.png)

Comment: Are your "dots" in one `ImageView`, or in multiple ones? How do you load them? Are they `.png` files, simple `shapes` or `Vector Drawables`?

Comment: Multiple ImageButtons. They are added on the run-time and will use a .png.

Comment: Android requires a lot of memory to do this, but there are many options to optimize this. If you only need simple squares, look into [VectorDrawables](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html). If you need to use `.png` files, [reduce the size of them](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).

Comment: Animations are laggy even if I dont use a png. @Amy

Comment: How did you get to this result? What else have you used?

Comment: I have set Margin parameters for each ImageButton to arrange them in a circular layout. @Amy

Comment: I mean instead of a `png` file..